# Changing PS4 Controller LED Colors using C#/.NET without DS4Windows

Tags: c#

I am attempting to programmatically change the color of both the center and corner lights on a PS4 controller using C# and .NET. I want to achieve this without relying on DS4Windows, as I prefer not to have an external dependency on it. Unfortunately, I couldn't find any resources or documentation to guide me through this process.

I attempted to explore the DS4Windows source code, but it proved challenging to understand. As an alternative, I also investigated the possibility of achieving this with Python but encountered similar difficulties.

If anyone has experience or insights into how I can accomplish this task using C# and .NET, or if there's a way to do it without requiring the installation of DS4Windows, I would greatly appreciate any guidance or pointers. Thank you!

*Edit:*

```
// P/Invoke declarations
[DllImport("DS4Windows.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public static extern int DS4Windows_Init();

// ... (other function declarations)

// Main function
static void Main()
{
    try
    {
        // Initialize DS4Windows
        DS4Windows_Init(); // <- Error occurs here
        // ... (rest of the code)
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"An error occurred: {ex.Message}");
    }
}
```

Comment: It looks like you've edited your question and decided to go down the DS4Windows route after all. Can you give us details of _"Error occurs here"_

Comment: The error is that ds4windows dll has no `DS4Windows_Init`.

Comment: You'll have to take a look at any documentation to determine the correct function/method/procedure names and parameters.